# SQL Server Inline CASE WHEN ISNULL and multiple checks

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have a column with some nulls. If that column is null, I want to condition output for it based on values in another column.

So `if case when null (if c=80 then 'planb'; else if c=90 then 'planc')`

How would you code that in an inline T-SQL statement?

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
COALESCE(YourColumn, CASE c WHEN 80 then 'planb' WHEN 90 THEN 'planc' END)
```

Comment: You can also use the ISNULL function instead of the COALESCE function if you want to force the returned value to be converted to the datatype of the first expression.

Comment: @Jake - Thanks, I never noticed that was a differentiator between the 2 before now!

Comment: Be carefull when using ISNULL vs COALESCE, they are not the same.  ISNULL will replace the characters with the replacement value, while COALESCE will substitute.  I can provide an example where the outcome will be different.

Comment: @Leons - `COALESCE(foo, bar)`  is basically short hand for for `CASE WHEN foo IS NOT NULL THEN foo ELSE bar END` not sure what distinction you are making between replacing and substitution can you give this example?

Comment: @Martin - In the example `DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(10); DECLARE @bar VARCHAR(2); SET @foo = ISNULL(@bar,'DEFAULT'); PRINT @foo` the outcome is that `@foo` will print 'DE' and not DEFAULT.  `COALESCE(@bar,DEFAULT')` will correctly set `@foo` to 'DEFAULT'.  In this case ISNULL and COALESCE is not the same.

Comment: @Martin - By the way - I like the use of COALESCE in your answer.  Very efficient.

Comment: @Leons - Ah right it gets cast to `varchar(2)` as per Jake's comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the nested case statement.  Assuming that the first column is called DataColumn.

```
CASE 
  WHEN DataColumn IS NULL THEN 
    CASE c 
      WHEN 80 THEN 'planb' 
      WHEN 90 THEN 'planc' 
      ELSE 'no plan' 
    END 
  ELSE DataColumn 
END
```